# How do I Animate a UWP Control XY Position in Code?

Tags: animation, uwp

I am trying to animate the position of a border control in code.  For the life of me I cannot see what is wrong with this code, but it I keep getting an error on Storyboard.Begin()

> "No installed components were detected. Cannot resolve TargetProperty
> (UIElement.RenderTransformProperty).(CompositeTransform.TranslateXProperty)
> on specified object.

Below is the code I am using:

```
Private Sub bdrTest1_PointerPressed(sender As Object, e As PointerRoutedEventArgs) Handles bdrTest1.PointerPressed

    Animate(1, -100, 2)

End Sub

Private AnimateToX As Integer
Private AnimateToY As Integer
Private IsAnimating As Boolean
Private WithEvents Storyboard As Storyboard

Private Sub Animate(dx As Integer, dy As Integer, dt As Double)

    bdrTest1.RenderTransform = New CompositeTransform

    Dim duration As New Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(dt))

    Dim DoubleAnimationX As New DoubleAnimation With {
        .Duration = duration,
        .EasingFunction = New ExponentialEase() With {.Exponent = 7, .EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut},
        .To = dx
    }
    AnimateToX = dx

    Dim DoubleAnimationY As New DoubleAnimation With {
        .Duration = duration,
        .EasingFunction = New ExponentialEase() With {.Exponent = 7, .EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut},
        .To = dy
    }
    AnimateToY = dy

    Storyboard = New Storyboard With {.Duration = duration}

    Storyboard.SetTarget(DoubleAnimationX, bdrTest1)
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(DoubleAnimationX, "(UIElement.RenderTransformProperty).(CompositeTransform.TranslateXProperty)")
    Storyboard.Children.Add(DoubleAnimationX)

    Storyboard.SetTarget(DoubleAnimationY, bdrTest1)
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(DoubleAnimationY, "(UIElement.RenderTransformProperty).(CompositeTransform.TranslateYProperty)")
    Storyboard.Children.Add(DoubleAnimationY)

    IsAnimating = True
    Storyboard.Begin()

End Sub

Private Sub Storyboard_Completed(sender As Object, e As Object) Handles Storyboard.Completed

    CType(sender, Storyboard).Stop()

    IsAnimating = False

End Sub
```

I am using slightly similar code to animate a large image in a scroll viewer on a page, and it works fine, but I can't seem to translate that to moving a simple control.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Several hours of web searching later, I see the error of my ways:

Simply dropped the 'Property' descriptor from the path names, thus changing:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(DoubleAnimationX, "(UIElement.RenderTransformProperty).(CompositeTransform.TranslateXProperty)")
```

to:

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(DoubleAnimationX, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)")
```

Now it works fine.